# Can I use ExtJs without License like JQuery?

Tags: jquery, extjs

Can I use ExtJs without License like JQuery?
Can I publish website using ExtJS without any permission from them?

Comment: FYI, jQuery is licensed under MIT or GPLv2.  Granted MIT is a liberal license, but a license nonetheless.

Comment: I think the reason you're getting different answers is because "use" is a vague statement. Either way, a license applies with any of those products, it's the limitations of the individual licenses you're after. If you're going the GPL route, you still have quite a bit of leeway even in a commercial context. However you couldn't for example repackage ExtJs and sell it as a product (without including the source you modified). But I believe you could even go so far as to sell it without modifications. Either way being more detailed in your question would probably lead to better answers.

Answer (score 3):

ExtJS GPL Licence means that if you are using ExtJS under GPL Licence, and not modifying ExtJS itself, then  you are Free to use ExtJS in whatever manner on any Website. But if you take ExtJS and start modifying ExtJS itself ( to make some better 'Super-Duper-ExtJS' Library ), then you have to share that with everyone, because if you start selling 'Super-Duper-ExtJS' to your Clients, then whats going to happen is that 'ExtJS-Company' finds itself Competing with Itself. I dont think you need to share your 'Website's Source-code' in any case. If you need to share your 'Websites source-code' ifself with other People while using ExtJS-GPL, then only the ExtJS-GPL Licence would start looking absurd, and you need to start looking at jQueryUI or DOJO ! But I dont think that 'ExtJS-Company' means to share your Websites-source just for the reason that you used their ExtJS Library ! What say .......

Comment: This seems much more in-line with my understanding of the GPL series of licenses.

Comment: This answer confuses the GPL and the LGPL. The LGPL does not require you to share your derivative works unless you modify the library itself. ExtJS is released under the GPL which requires you to share all derivative works. It is hard to say if your web site is a derivative work of the libraries you use to create it; that is a question for a lawyer. But I would buy a license from Sencha if I wanted to use ExtJS on a project with a requirement to protect intellectual property.

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: I am not a lawyer.

Yes you can use Extjs on your web site without asking permission (as long as you are not distributing it). There are numerous SO questions regarding the GPL, so I won't go into much detail.

If you're coding an application for a client, that is only meant to be used by that company. You do not have to disclose your source code. You do on the other hand if you create a web application that you sell (or distribute) to several companies.

They do offer some great products though. So feel free to support them by buying a license.

Comment: You can use ExtJS on your web site without permission, BUT you are **required to publish the whole source code of your site**, e.g. including **all your .php files**, under a GPL v3 compatible license. This is the "*viral effect*" of the GPL! Now you are warned! :)

Comment: In my opinion you are incorrect. What you claim does not apply if you are not *distributing* it.

Comment: the license FAQ on their website says if you develop a product for a client then you need a license and so does the client. That would be a sellable product, not a website from what I understood.

Comment: What their FAQ claims is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

ExtJS is available under both [GPL v3](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) for open source projects and under a commercial license for proprietary applications.  The license terms for ExtJS can be found [here](http://www.extjs.com/products/license.php); have a look at that page for details.

That said, I'm not a lawyer, and if you're unsure about what's ok in your particular situation, you should seek legal advice from a professional.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a little more research, I'm taking back what I said with my comments. Take a look at this page (which is probably a little biased, but adds a lot of useful information):

http://pablotron.org/?cid=1556

Their position is intentionally vague, and some of the comments they've posted seem to imply that you'd be required to publish unrelated code on your website that was loaded at the same time. While I don't think this would hold up to a careful review of the GPL, most companies won't take the risk and just buy a license. These people are bad stewards of open source software.

Comment: If you use the ExtJS library, you accept the terms of use that the license is distributed with. They shared their library under the GPL so it can be used by people who are willing to share on an equal basis. It isn't a "bad steward of open source". If you don't like the terms of the license, then don't use the library.

Comment: @resplin did you read your own comment you wrote above? Because of the uncertainty of whether a website that uses the library is a derivative work or not, any company and even you by your admission would buy the license. I believe this vagueness is desired by them. That makes them bad stewards of software. They're not technically breaking the law (probably), but enough FUD surrounds the licensing that any commercial entity will just pay the license, needed or not. That is dishonest at best.